# How to display page not found error page when an invalid API request is made in nodejs and reactjs app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have not done this before I tried to see how it is done online but didn't see any reliable method. I keep seeing only the `react.js` part. I have a Middleware in `node.js` that returns `route does not exist`

```
const notFound = (req, res) => res.status(404).send('Route does not exist')
```

And I serve it this way in the `app.js`

```
app.use(notFoundMiddleware);


app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
})
```

This works in postman when I tested an invalid route. However, since I am serving my frontend below it, the code below it doesn't work. If I place the `not found middleware` below the frontend files, the frontend files would be served but the `not found middleware` won't work anymore.

How Am I supposed to serve `not found middleware` and serve it in frontend using `react.js`?

Comment: You can check status code of response and redirect to 404 page accordingly.

Comment: Yes, forgive my armature question. How do I make the api call for this middleware judging from the code I showed up here? I am sensing I will be using useEffect in react for this but how do I link the api call that would trigger this response in the first place?

Comment: Or do I include that in all my routes one by one and access the response in reactjs? Or can I access the response in any place within my reactjs? Do I really need this in backend or should I simply create the 404 page in react alone?